# Selenium wait and click using nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium

I'm trying to login on fifa ultimate team... but i don't know why if i try to use wait the click action did not anything...
basicly my url is https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/
and the button i need to click is Login
any idea?

```
require('chromedriver');
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var until = webdriver.until;
var By = webdriver.By;

async function myMain(){

    let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/');
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('btn-standard call-to-action')), 15000);
    await driver.findElement(By.className('btn-standard call-to-action')).click();
}

myMain();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector might not be quite right. Try this:

```
  await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//button[text()='Login']")),15000);
  let loginButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Login']"));

  await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(loginButton ,15000));

  await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Login']")).click();
```

Comment: thanks for answer.

I tried and get that message:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()='Login']"}

Because the element take some seconds to load... Did you tried on your browser?

Comment: My apologies, my solution did not take the initial long loading time into account. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: no problems... 

I got that error "TypeError: element.isDisplayed is not a function" in await driver.wait line...

any idea?

Comment: `element.isDisplayed` is meant to take an existing WebElement, while `elementVisible` takes By as parameter. Updated my example to use `elementVisible` instead, and added additional wait on `elementIsEnabled`.

Comment: thank you soo much!!!

it works!!!

you only need to add an ) after loginButton ,15000

Comment: @MatheusCampos great, happy to help